# How to set variable when button is clicked using Razor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a button that when clicked, will change the value of the variable `_name`. But this doesn't work when I click `Change Name` then `Refresh`.

**View**

```
@{
    var _name = ViewContext.RouteData.Values["name"].ToString();
}

<div>
    <h1>Hello, @name!</h1>
    <button type="button" onclick="@(_name = "John Doe")">Change Name</button>

    <button type="button" onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("MyAction", new { name = _name })'">Refresh</button>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult MyAction(string name = "default") {
    ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["name"] = name;

    return View;
}
```

On refresh, the h1 should say "Hello, John Doe!". What is the right way of setting a variable inside HTML using Razor?

Comment: I think you are confusing server-side and client-side logic.  A razor variable exists on the server and only during the current request.

Comment: Doesn't the `Url.Action()` send the new value when I hit the Refresh button? @radium

Comment: The `onclick="@(_name = "John Doe")"` doesn't set the server-side variable `_name` on a client-side click. All server-side code executes *before* the HTML (without any server-side code, just the results of that code) is sent to the browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are going in wrong direction. do this

1. put the `name` in a property in your `model`
2. create a hidden with `Html.HiddenFor` for `name`
3. change the value of hidden field with `javascript` on `onClick`
4. when the form is posted you have the new value of name in your model and you don't need `new { name = _name }` any more

instead of having `name` in your model and `hiddenfor` you can use this as alternative

```
Html.Hidden("name", ViewData("name"))
```

then for your link make url by this hidden value

> Also using `RouteData` is not a good idea for your purpose, I would recommend to use `ViewData["xxx"]` instead

Comment: I stripped down my code for simplicity purposes, but what if I'm already passing in (let's say) a Food model? It would not be ideal to include the name on that model since it's the person's name, and not the food's.

Comment: I'll try this out and will let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Look up and understand how ViewData works before implementing this change!